# Facebook bad response code with Headway theme and WordPress SEO

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I’ve searched the web up and down for hours w/o finding an answer. I simply cannot post/share my recent posts to Facebook and show anything other than the url. No image or excerpt.

I'm using Headway Wordpress Theme and Wordpress SEO to automatically add all og tags.

Here's the most recent post source og tags:

```
    <!-- Title -->
<title>My Landlord Wants Me To Add My Boyfriend To My Lease. Do I Have To? | San Francisco Tenant Lawyers</title>
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.4.24 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir"/>
<meta name="description" content="Tell your landlord that it&#039;s beneficial to her to allow you to add your boyfriend as a subtenant. If you move out she can increase the rent to market rate."/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://crowandrose.com/2014/01/landlord-wants-add-boyfriend-lease/" />
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/104583554159124890350/about"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Landlord Wants Me To Add My Boyfriend To My Lease. Do I Have To? | San Francisco Tenant Lawyers" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Tell your landlord that it&#039;s beneficial to her to allow you to add your boyfriend as a subtenant. If you move out she can increase the rent to market rate." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://crowandrose.com/2014/01/landlord-wants-add-boyfriend-lease/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="San Francisco Tenant Lawyers" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Crow-Rose-Attorneys-At-Law/68192891917" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/pages/crow-rose-attorneys-at-law/68192891917" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="consent" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Lease" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Rent Ordinance" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Roommates" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Subletting" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Tenant Law" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-01-22T10:37:56+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2014-01-22T10:49:27+00:00" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="103449812457" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://crowandrose.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/gift-horse-e1390405080789.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Evict_This"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="San Francisco Tenant Lawyers"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@https://twitter.com/evict_this"/>
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

Until November 23, 2013. I was able to share sporadically with the thumbnail and excerpt showing. I say off and on, never consistent.

All of my Facebook post/share attempts show this in the Facebook debugger.

> Response Code  403
>   Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
>   Bad Response Code  URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
>   Warning
>   Errors That Must Be Fixed
>   Missing Required Property  The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.

The og tags are all in place and have been for years. Clearly the 'og:type' property *is* present.

Today I deleted my facebook app in case that was the culprit. Still all 403 errors.

I just don’t get it. Anything you can suggest? Is there something I can add to .htaccess?

My site is http://crowandrose.com.

Answer (score 0):

I allowed facebook's crawlers in my .htaccess per this:

Facebook Crawler

A number of Platform services such as Social Plugins and the Open Graph require our systems to be able to reach your web pages. We recognize that there are situations where you might not want these pages on the public Internet, during testing or for other security reasons.

To facilitate this, you should make exceptions in your security systems to allow Facebook to crawl these pages by adding the following IP ranges, accurate as of March 2013.

```
31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
173.252.64.0/18
204.15.20.0/22

2401:db00::/32
2620:0:1c00::/40
2a03:2880::/32
```

Please note that these IP ranges can and do change regularly, so you should periodically run the following command to receive an updated list -

`whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route`

My last question is, Where do I enter the command?